# Is it possible to see my telemetry locally in Visual Studio when debugging a containerised app?

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, logging, azure-application-insights

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API. It is configured to write its telemetry to an Application Insights instance in Azure, and before it was containerised I'd simply omit the instrumentation key from the debug config in order to view telemetry in Visual Studio's Application Insights window.

I've now added Docker support for this API using Docker Compose as my orchestrator. Now when I debug using my Docker Compose configuration I no longer see my telemetry within Visual Studio. I haven't changed anything directly in the app. So is it possible to still see telemetry for a debug session locally in Visual Studio when running in a Docker container?

Comment: I'm not clear about something. Do you deploy the telemetry in the docker via the Visual Studio? Where do you install the docker? Azure or local?

Comment: Linux container running locally on Docker for Windows. Expecting telemetry to report into Visual Studio's debugging diagnostics tools the same as when debugging locally on IIS Express. Not explicitly deploying anything related to telemetry. The app is configured to use Application Insights, with instrumentation key set to empty string.

Comment: Related: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/debug-session-telemetry-not-found-when-running-in/1255656